I have a problem inserting into my datagrid
I work in C# with WPF. I try to browse line by line my datagrid to insert different data in each combobox "schedules" in relation to the user’s name. So far I fill all the combobox with the data of the last user
I tried
foreach (DataGridRow Line in DataGridGroupe) 

The DataGridGroupe does not exist in the current context. While in my XAML, this is the name I gave it: x:Name="DataGridGroupe"
I also tried DataGridGroupe.insert(index, EdTcombine); but still the same problem.
This is my code:
foreach (USAGERS us in _ListeUsagers)
{
    if (us.IsSelected == true)
    {
        List<EMPLOIDUTEMPS> EdTassocie = new List<EMPLOIDUTEMPS>();

        if (ListEdTTemps == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (EMPLOIDUTEMPS e in ListEdTTemps)
            {
                if (e.CodeUsager == us.CodeUsager)
                {
                    EdTassocie.Add(e);
                }
            }

            EdTassocie = EdTassocie.Distinct().ToList();
            EdTcombine = new List<EMPLOIDUTEMPS>();

            EMPLOIDUTEMPS separateur = new EMPLOIDUTEMPS();
            separateur.Nom = "----------------------------";

            if (EdTassocie.Count > 0 && EmploisDuTemps.Count > 0)
            {
                EdTcombine.AddRange(EdTassocie);
                EdTcombine.Add(separateur);
                EdTcombine.AddRange(EmploisDuTemps);
            }
            else if (EmploisDuTemps.Count > 0)
            {
                 EdTcombine.AddRange(EmploisDuTemps);
            }
        }
    }
}

I have the right data I should be able to insert them in the right line before the new passage on the first foreach

Where and how is DataGridGroupe defined in your XAML markup?

I would try to verify you can access that control before doing anything, are you in the ViewModel or in code-behind? If in the ViewModel then you shouldn't be trying to reference a control directly but should be using binding instead, if in code-behind then intellisense should see the control as soon as you give it a name.
In the attached image I gave a <Grid> a name of "grid1" and you can see I can see it in the intellisense drop down. xaml name reference (code-behind)

Agree yes I am on the ViewModel but my link only puts the data of the last to everyone instead of doing it to each user.    Here is the part of my XAML that manages it      


Sorry I'm not sure I follow, if you're in the ViewModel then you can't (and shouldn't) reference controls directly, but in your question you say you're trying to reference the DataGrid directly?

I’m a novice intern, so I try things. in fact the code I put at the beginning works but it is EdTcombine that transmits its data at the end of the first foreach. I can’t get it to pass every iteration in the loop

Of course, I understand, if the ComboBox controls are within DataGrid cells then that adds a level of complexity and I would advise adding a ViewModel for each of those, but perhaps for now you could try do the insertion in code-behind (of where the DataGrid lives) to prove a point, then afterwards look at implementing additional ViewModels.

I just saw that my code works well, it just puts the info on each combobox instead of just put it on the user’s in my datagrid
